# How to use containerd?

Tags: containerd

I want to start with containerd, but I always get one of these two errors:

```
time="2022-05-18T18:08:58+02:00" level=fatal msg="cannot access containerd socket \"\\\\\\\\.\\\\pipe\\\\containerd-containerd\": open \\\\.\\pipe\\containerd-containerd: The system cannot find the file specified."
```

or:

```
time="2022-05-18T18:09:39+02:00" level=fatal msg="unknown service containerd.services.images.v1.Images: not implemented"
```

When I get the second error I ran the containerd command in another terminal.
Also I'm on windows and I installed the nerdctl because I saw that they recommend it in the getting started tutorial on github.
Thanks in advance